# Creating a shebang pointing portably to an interpreter in the folder of a script

Tags: shell-script, shebang

I have a JS file (`file.js`) that I want to have executed as a command line shell script through nodejs (iojs actually); I'm using MINGW Git Bash on Windows.

The standard way to do it is to put the following shebang in the JS file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

However, I want to pass a cmd line flag to node to activate V8 harmony features, i.e. I want an equivalent of

```
node --harmony_arrow_functions file.js
```

when run just as

```
./file.js
```

without the need to pass the flag manually.

Using

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --harmony_arrow_functions
```

does not work.

After considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/8108970/245966 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5735690/245966 I created the following solution:

```
$ ls
file.js nodeharmony.sh

$ cat nodeharmony.sh
#!/bin/sh
exec node --harmony_arrow_functions "$@"

$ cat file.js
#!/bin/sh nodeharmony.sh               # or ./nodeharmony.sh, doesn't matter
console.log("Hello world")

$ ./file.js    # this works fine
Hello world
```

But the problem is that when I execute it from another folder, the shell tries to find `nodeharmony.sh` in the current working directory, not the directory of `file.js`:

```
$ cd ..
$ ./subfolder/file.js
/bin/sh: ./nodeharmony.sh: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to create a portable shebang in `file.js` such that I can run `file.js` from whatever folder, without resorting to having my custom interpreter (`nodeharmony.sh`) available in the `PATH`?

**Edit:**

**The JS file has to remain a valid JavaScript file, so it can not have more than an initial `#!` line**, i.e. when I change `file.js` to be

```
#!/bin/sh
exec $(dirname $0)/nodeharmony.sh "$0"
console.log("Hello world")
```

then the shell properly passes the dir name and argument but it fails on Node side since the file is not a valid JS code:

```
$ ./subfolder/file.js
d:\CODE\subfolder\file.js:2
exec $(dirname $0)/nodeharmony.sh $0
     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:16)
    ...
```

**Edit 2:**

I'd also like to keep the possibility to run my script through

```
./file.js
```

as well as

```
node --harmony_arrow_functions ./file.js
```

So the suggested hack to `sed` the file contents, delete header and pipe it to node in the shebang is not good in this context, since the latter execution will be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: (The original answer still responds to the stated question, but indeed makes file.js not a valid JS file).  In order to allow the desired behavior, follows a `shebang + 1st-line-combination` that will feed the file.js through `node` skipping the two first lines, thus feeding it with just the JS code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '1,2d' $0 |node --harmony_arrow_functions; exit $?
/* Your JS code begins here */
```

--- Below the original answer ---

If you can count as certain your interpreter will be in the same directory of the interpreted file (which is the stated question), you can use `$(dirname $0)` to obtain its path.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec $(dirname $0)/nodeharmony.sh "$0" "$@"
```

In this case, when executing

```
$ cd ..
$ ./subfolder/file.js
```

The `$(dirname $0)` will resolve to `./subfolder`, so exec will use `./subfolder/nodeharmony.sh` as the interpreter.

Comment: I used `$0` instead of `$@` to pass the original file name, but anyway this solution does not work, see my edit

Comment: @jakub.g, ok.  Just edited the answer with a solution that will skip the first two lines and feed the source to node using a pipe.

Comment: That's pretty hacky but it worked for me (`sed '1,2d' "$0" | node --harmony_arrow_functions ; exit $?`), +1, thanks :)

Comment: I just realized your hack is not bulletproof since it prohibits passing the parameters to the script. E.g. `./file.js -param`, normally this sets `process.argv[2] == "-param"`, but when piping the script text to the node interpreter, this gets lost. Making this work would probably need even more hacks, not sure I need it that much ;)

Comment: Don't know much about JS to write a stub and test.  Just try adding a `"$@"` or a `-- "$@"` right after the `--harmony_arrow_functions` and let me know if it works.

Comment: Nope it doesn't; you can test with a simple JS file being `console.log(process.argv)` and then `node file.js -q` vs `echo console.log(process.argv) | node -q`. The latter fails with "bad option: -q".

Also the `sed` hack makes the script work fine when run as `./file.js` but makes it fail when run as `node ./file.js`. I guess there can't be produced a good workaround following this way.

Comment: I installed the interpreter (nodejs-0.10.33).  What does this option (--harmony_arrow_functions) do?  Could not find any reference in the man page.

Comment: I actually use [iojs](https://iojs.org/) which is a fork of node (but still has `node` executable for backward compat reasons); It enables V8 engine experimental features to run; see `node --v8-options`

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a Node script which is also a valid shell script to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
//usr/bin/env node --harmony_arrow_functions "$0" "$@"; exit $?

console.log("Hello world")
```

Saving this as `file.js` produces a script which can be run from anywhere. It relies on `//` being equivalent to `/`; I haven’t tested this on Windows...

Comment: Interesting but doesn't work on Windows, AFAIK // is used by Git Bash as the prefix for network shares (equivalent to ``\\`` prefix in Windows).